# Solving trigonometric equations to the fourth power.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$\sin^4(x)-\sin^2(x)=0$$

My work:

Let $t=\sin^2(x)$

Rewrite the original equation as: $t^2-t$

Factor: $t(t-1)$

$t=1$, $t=0$

What do I do from here?

Comment: Now, you need to solve the equations $\sin^2 x = 0$ and $\sin^2 x = 1$. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Yes, arcsin(0)=x and arcsin(1)=x. So x=0, x=pi/2

Answer (score 4):

Change variables back from $t$ to $x$, then solve each equation separately:

\begin{align*}
t = 1 &\iff \sin^2 x = 1 \\
&\iff \sin x = \pm 1 \\
&\iff x = \frac{\pi}{2} + n\pi ~~~~~\text{where } n \in \mathbb Z
\end{align*}

Likewise:

\begin{align*}
t = 0 &\iff \sin^2 x = 0 \\
&\iff \sin x = 0 \\
&\iff x = n\pi ~~~~~\text{where } n \in \mathbb Z
\end{align*}

Combining the two above cases, we obtain:
$$
x = \frac{n\pi}{2} ~~~~~\text{where } n \in \mathbb Z
$$

Answer (score 2):

You have almost done it. From there you get $$\sin^2x=0$$ or $$\sin^2 x=1$$. Hence Either $\sin x=1$, $\sin x=-1$ or $\sin x=0$. So you get  $x = k\pi$, $ k \in Z$ or $ x=k \pi \pm \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ where $ k \in Z$

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this approach:

$$\sin^4(x) - \sin^2(x) = \sin^2(x)(\sin^2(x)-1) = \sin^2(x)(-\cos^2(x)).$$

The last equality follows from Pythagorean identity. So then all you have to solve is

$$ 0 = \sin^2(x)\cos^2(x).$$

Or if you want to use double angle formula,

$$ 0 = \frac{1}{4}\sin^2(2x).$$

Answer (score 1):

Why bother with substitution? Just factor it directly

$$
0 = (\sin x +1)(\sin x - 1)\sin^2 x
$$
and solve the equations resulting from setting each distinct factor equal to zero:

$$
\sin x +1 =0 \iff x=-\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi
$$

$$
\sin x -1 =0 \iff x=\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi
$$

$$
\sin x =0 \iff x=k\pi
$$

Putting these together, the product vanishes precisely when

$$x=\boxed{\dfrac{k\pi}{2}}$$
for integral $k$.